# Estoy realizando un formulario con ajax y el problema es que envia dos veces al servidor

Tags: jquery

Tengo un formulario

```
<form id="calendarizar" autocomplete="off" method="get" action="proceso.php">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="validateButton2">Submit</button>
</form>
```

con esto llamo

```
$('#calendarizar').submit(function (ev) {  
    $.ajax({
        type: ('#calendarizar').attr('method'),
        url: $('#calendarizar').attr('action'),
        data: $('#calendarizar').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Datos enviados !!!'); 
        }
    });
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

Lo que hace es llamar dos veces proceso.php entonces duplica los movimentos, alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Probaste poner el `ev.preventDefault()` antes de la llamada a AJAX? Por otro lado, te falta el `$` en el "type".

Comment: Me sigue enviando doble el proceso al action

Comment: Fijate si no te está apareciendo algún error en la consola. Con F12 en tu explorador te abre las herramientas de desarrollo, fijate si no aparece algo en al consola.

Answer (score 1):

Sacale el action al form y agrega el destino en el atributo url directo, y en method del form dejaria post siempre mas alla del metodo que uses en la peticion que mandas.
Si usas un button submit en el js antes de salir de la funcion tenes que pasarle un return false para que no envie el formulario por el metodo tradicional despues de ejecutar la llamada de ajax

Answer (score 0):

Tal como indica Pushumo, tu código quedaría así:

```
$('#calendarizar').submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: $('#calendarizar').attr('method'),
      url: $('#calendarizar').attr('action'),
      data: $('#calendarizar').serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        alert('Datos enviados !!!');
      }
    });
    return false;   
  });
```